# Getting data from API and sum 2 values for each year

Tags: python, api

I want to get data from API where the structure looks like:
district - passed - gender - year - value
This api shows how many people from country passed exam, but it has 2 rows for the same year but gender are different (male and female).
I want to sum value for each year, for example:

CountryA passed male 2019 12

CountryA passed female 2019 30

So result should be 42.
Unfortunately my method return only female's value.

I was trying something like this:

```
def task2(self,data,district=None):
    passed = {stat.year: stat.amount for stat in data
              if self.getPercentageAmountOfPassed(stat.status,stat.district,stat.year)}


def getPercentageAmountOfPassed(self,status,district,year):
    return status == 'passed' and district == 'CountryA' and year <= 2019
```

Im pretty sure that I got data from api, because I was solving other examples with other parameters

EXAMPLE OF DATA:
[year][disctrict][amount][passed][gender]

[Data(2010.0, Polska,160988.0,przystąpiło,mężczyźni),

Data(2010.0, Polska,205635.0,przystąpiło,kobiety),

Data(2011.0, Polska,150984.0,przystąpiło,mężczyźni)]

Comment: Can you show a sample value of `data` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh added

Comment: This data doesn't have numbers to add up e.g. 12 and 30

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh edited again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you overwrite previous entries when you have the same year. You need to sum them instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def sum_per_year(data):
    passed = defaultdict(int)
    for stat in data:
        if getPercentageAmountOfPassed(stat.status, stat.district, stat.year):
            passed[int(stat.year)] += stat.amount
    return passed
```